# How to Bold and Change Font Size of Chart Title

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, data-visualization

I can create Box Plot Chart dynamically. The issue I faced now is I have no idea how to **bold** and change the **font size** of the **chart title**.

I have researched online for awhile but could not figure out how to do this.

This is my codes:

```
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
                Chart1.DataSource = tg;
                Chart1.Width = 600;
                Chart1.Height = 350;

                Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
                List<object> lst = tg.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

                foreach (DataRow row in tg.Rows)
                    Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["VALUE"], new object[] { row["Min"], row["Max"], row["Avg"], row["Percentile25"], row["Percentile50"], row["Percentile75"] });

                Chart1.Series[0]["PixelPointWidth"] = "38";
                string title = (tg.Rows[0]["TITLE"].ToString());
                Chart1.Titles.Add(title);

                //create chartareas
                ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();

                ca.AxisX = new Axis();
                ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
                ca.AxisY = new Axis();
                ca.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
                Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

                //databind
                Chart1.DataBind();
                Chart1.Visible = true;

                panel.Controls.Add(Chart1);
```

Question: How to **Bold** Chart **Title**?

How to Change **Font Size** of Chart **Title**?

Appreciate if someone could help me on this. Thanks!

Regards,

Felicia

Comment: Look at the HTML that this code generates. And from there, you could see how the title is rendered. You will the be able to format it, using css. Or you could post the html in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Title title = new Title();
        title.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
        title.Text = "My Chart Title";
        Chart1.Titles.Add(title);
```

Comment: btw @jstreet, do you know how to change the font of axis X label? I tried like this : Chart1.Series[0].Font=new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold); but doesn't work :(

Comment: Try: `Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font();`

Comment: In general, you should get familiar with using VS Designer. It makes it much quicker and easier to locate and configure properties like this, related to the chart appearance. And use code behind only for handling data.

Comment: oh ok I will, thanks @jstreet for helping me again! :)