# Changing Chart Font VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to change the font size of the title and legend of a chart? something along the lines of:

`MyChart.Legends("MyLegend").Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25)`???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936053/how-to-bold-and-change-font-size-of-chart-title and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416493/how-to-set-different-label-in-legend-in-pie-chart

Comment: I've tried those already, but they're c#. I'm looking for Vb.net

Comment: No big deal buddy: `Dim title As New Title : title.Font = New Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold) : title.Text = "My Chart Title" : Chart1.Titles.Add(title)` Almost the same.

Comment: Ive tried this, but im getting an error when defining title as `Title`.  "Type 'Title' is not defined." Do i need a library?

Comment: @Kxpr Does the code have `Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
`? There should have been a red squiggly line under "Title" - if you hover over it then it will suggest some possible fixes, including adding that Imports for you.

Comment: Imported it, now Title is recognised as a class. Thank you.